# Linked list not Printing?

Tags: c, linked-list, output

Okay this is making me sweat. I have a program that is compiling, but I am not receiving my desired output when I execute it on gcc, instead the output is `Error`. I am pretty sure my code and call for `Print` is at least correct. I can't find any error in my program that would mess up the output.
This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;
node *Inserttail(node *head, int x){
    node *temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    node *temp1 = head;
    if(head==NULL)
        return temp;
    else if(head->next ==NULL){
        head ->next = temp;
        return head;
    }
    while(head->next != NULL)
        head = head->next;
    head->next = temp;
    return temp1;
}
void Print(node *head){
    if(head == NULL)
        printf("Error");
    while(head != NULL){
        printf("%d ", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
node *Deletemultiples(node *head, int k){
    node *temp = head, *old = temp;
    if(head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(head->data == 1)
        head= head->next;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        if(temp->data %k ==0 && temp->data != k)
            old->next = temp->next;
        old=temp;
        temp= temp->next;
    }
    return head;
}
void Freelist(node *head){
    node *temp = head;
    while(head != NULL){
        head = head -> next;
        free(temp);
        temp = head;
    }
}
int main(){
    node *head = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=1000; i++)
        head = Inserttail(head, i);
    for(i=2; i<=32; i++){
        head = Deletemultiples(head, i);
    }
    Print(head);
    Freelist(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Because of the if statement before the printf, I believe there is something wrong with head, I just can't find the issue.Any thoughts?

Comment: It's working perfectly fine for me. I get a list of prime numbers.

Comment: Works for me. I get a list of what looks like prime numbers up to 1000.

Comment: what `gcc` version are you using? I'm compiling it on Repl.it which has gcc version 4.6.3

Comment: Interesting I tried it on  gcc and devc++ and it didn't work there either, but seems to work fine on several online compilers.

Comment: I tried running it, but I think you're missing a `}` in your print function.

Comment: @narusin I am using version 4.8.4

Comment: @below_avg_st what compiler are you using?

Comment: Can't see any issue with the logic really. Only problem I can see is that you aren't ever freeing memory when deleting items from the list.

Comment: @Matt do you have a suggestion on how to free it? Not what I intentionally posted on but I haven't been able to find a way to do it because of the logic I used for my delete method.

Comment: @below_avg_st store the current pointer, move onto the next, then delete the stored one. https://gist.github.com/MattDiesel/1eb6167304f5e23b98c1fa9cd6346736

Comment: I think your `Deletemultiples` function will not able to delete the element at the beginning of the list.

Comment: @RajeevSingh true.

Comment: @RajeevSingh good point I forgot to delete the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is correct. i run it under ubuntu 16.04 LTS with gcc 5.4.0 and
all things are OK.

[Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRlpF.png)